# Is there a better way to combine these dataframes and match values?

Tags: r, dataframe, left-join, custom-function

I have two dataframes that I have combined using `left_join()`

data1 can be simplified to something like...

```
Date <- as.Date(c('2011-7-26','2011-7-26','2010-11-1','2010-11-1','2009-5-10','2009-5-10','2008-3-25','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2007-3-14'))
Location <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")
Result <- sample(1:30, 10)
data1 <- data.frame(Date,Location,Result)
```

data2 can be simplified to something like...

```
Date <- as.Date(c('2011-7-26','2009-5-10','2007-3-14'))
Flow_A <- c(6,2,9)
Flow_B <- c(10,11,25)
data2 <- data.frame(Date,Flow_A,Flow_B)
```

After combining by date, I have this

```
data3 <- left_join(data2, data1, by = "Date")

        Date Flow_A Flow_B Location Result
1 2011-07-26      6     10        A     11
2 2011-07-26      6     10        B     17
3 2009-05-10      2     11        A      6
4 2009-05-10      2     11        B     22
5 2007-03-14      9     25        A     20
6 2007-03-14      9     25        B      1
```

Each value in Result corresponds to a specific Location (A or B) and I want to attach the correct values for Flow (Flow_A or Flow_B) to that row according to location (i.e. combine columns Flow_A and Flow_B into one column 'Flow' with just the correct value). I have been able to do this using a combination of `mutate()`,`ifelse()`,`grepl()`,and very simple functions:

```
a <- data3$Flow_A
Choose_A <- function(a) {
  return(a)}
d <- data3$Flow_B
Choose_B <- function(b) {
  return(b)} 

data3 <- mutate(data3, Flow =
             ifelse(grepl("A", Location), Choose_A(a), 
             ifelse(grepl("B", Location), Choose_B(b),NA)))

        Date Flow_A Flow_B Location Result Flow
1 2011-07-26      6     10        A     11    6
2 2011-07-26      6     10        B     17   10
3 2009-05-10      2     11        A      6    2
4 2009-05-10      2     11        B     22   11
5 2007-03-14      9     25        A     20    9
6 2007-03-14      9     25        B      1   25
```

But this seems rather clunky. Is there a better (more efficient) way to achieve this?

Please excuse my ignorance - I'm still learning!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a vector of column numbers to extract from each row using `match` and create a matrix with `cbind` which is used to subset relevant value from either `'Flow_A'` or `'Flow_B'` depending on `Location` column.

```
column_num <- match(paste0('Flow_', data3$Location), names(data3))
row_num <- seq_len(nrow(data3))
data3$Flow <- data3[cbind(row_num, column_num)]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! It seems my initial attempt was the most convoluted way possible of doing this...

Comment: The one thing I want to note (for other noobs like myself) is that in using this method the created 'Flow' column is a character class, not a numeric, so `as.numeric()` should be used if planning to use binary operators on the data.